# Export a fixed range quickly using FreeFile

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the values for a fixed range of cells (constantly changing) out into a text file at regular intervals as cleanly as possible.

I've got as far as putting one cell value into the filename of the txt:

```
        FF = FreeFile()
        Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("A" & cell.Row).Value & ".txt" For Output As #FF
        Print #FF, cell.Text
        Close #FF
```

But I want to put the data into the file, and leave the name alone.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: you want to keep the name of the file and just add to the file?

Comment: Yes - the file will be overwritten with the new data. Perhaps I should ignore Freefile and use a .CSV export? But I find it horribly slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly changing"?  Do you need the file to be rewritten several times per second, or several times per month?

Comment: Usually every few seconds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to your VBA code:

Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Delete the file and write your new one. This will give it the same name every time and will be `yourFile.txt`. Your directory will then have `yourFile.xlsx` and `yourFile.txt`.

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If fso.FileExists(Replace(Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsx", ".txt"), ".xls", ".txt")) Then
    fso.DeleteFile (Replace(Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsx", ".txt"), ".xls", ".txt"))
End If

FF = FreeFile()
Open Replace(Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsx", ".txt"), ".xls", ".txt") For Output As #FF
Print #FF, cell.Text
Close #FF
```

Comment: Thanks will try this tomorrow!

Comment: You will probably have to add some sort of `while(!File.Exists(yourFile.txt)) { }` to whatever program is reading this file in case it tries to read the file when it's not there.